# Unusual JQuery tags in HTML elements in IE (Internet Explorer)

Tags: html, internet-explorer

```
<html jQuery18303543510380473041="6">
    <head jQuery18303543510380473041="10">
    <body jQuery18303543510380473041="34">
```

This is screwing up my page in IE.  Has anyone seen this.  Can you explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed. Try use last version of JQuery.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3254